# Cocos2d update() strange behaviour

Tags: cocos2d-x, updates

I have a strange floating (Heisenbug) behavoiur when scheduling `update(float deltaTime)` selector in my `class MainSceneLayer: public CCLayer`.

`update(float deltaTime)` function increases `m_totalTimePassed` variable (class member; `m_totalTimePassed += deltaTime;`) and updates `CCLabelTTF` content to show how much time has passed.

On Windows, this works fine. But **sometimes** on iPad2 or iPad3 `m_totalTimePassed` is updating about 2 times faster than real time is.

Requesting any help and ideas. Maybe, i've set up my scene wrong, or smth else ?

Comment: I am scheduling `update()` with `CCNode::scheduleUpdate()`

Comment: it should be ccTime not float (on some OS like OSX ccTime is actually double, if you use float it will be interpreted as 0

Comment: @LearnCocos2D it is float on cocos2d-x. this is different from cocos2d.

Comment: Is this solved yet? If not, please be more specific by including more relevant code. If it is, what was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: The problem is solved now -- there was a mistake in my own code which caused memory corruption (rotten pointer usage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in my own code which caused memory corruption (rotten pointer usage).